# how to remove all style inside the container div '<div class=“woocommerce”>'?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom plugin for woocommerce an copied templates folder to my plugin /woocommerce. now I have to show a fixed layout that does not reflect with any themes. Can I disable all CSS for the particular custom div(by id or fixed class). Is there any way to either disable all styles within that div or override my custom shortcode to all over (must be the same in any condition)?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question well, you wish to disable the CSS Styles defined by Woocommerce.

Just add the following line of code to achieve this objective,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

For more info, visit
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

Comment: Thanks for the replay. but I only need woocommerce default CSS and my plugin style.css | I am using a static template and template_include filter to override all others.